# primitive == Wrapper converts to primitive == primitive or Wrapper == Wrapper?

Tags: java, equals, numeric, boxing, unboxing

I suppose that conversions described in jls are sorted according the priority.
first has greate priority.

[jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Thus I solved that `Boxing` has greater priority than `Unboxing`. I decided to check this assumption.

research following code:

```
public class BoxingUnboxingPriority {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int sn = 1000;
        Integer isn1= new Integer(sn);
        System.out.println(sn == isn1 );

    }
}
```

**out:**

```
true
```

What is boxing? is just `new Integer(primitiveInt)`

I changed the code a bit

```
int sn = 1000;
Integer isn1= new Integer(sn);
Integer isn2= new Integer(sn);
System.out.println(isn1 == isn2 );
```

**out:**

`false`

Thus I made mistake.

Please clarify me this issue.

Comment: Use `.equals` instead of `==` to compare the objects. `==` checks to see if they are the **same object**, which they aren't as you used `new` to create them both. `.equals` would return `true` because they represent the same number.

Comment: @Andremoniy  там вообще не про джаву даже!

Comment: @JonK it is question from test

Comment: @gstackoverflow сорри, был не прав

Answer (score 2):

The [relevant section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> **15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=**
>
> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands ([§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).

So:

```
Integer o = 1;
int i = 1;
boolean b = o == i;
```

...is equivalent to:

```
boolean b = o.intValue() == i;
```

Where both are of type *Integer* neither is a primitive numeric type - they are both [object references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3).

Comment: What is numeric type?

Comment: [The numeric types are the integral types and the floating-point types.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

Answer (score 1):

When you use primitive with a Wrapper object, that wrapper object will be unboxed and then the operation will be applied.

In your first case, when you comparing `sn` with `isn1`, `isn1` will be unboxed and the value will be compared. So you got `true`.

In second case, `isn1`, `isn2` are two different object, so `==` operator will give `false`

Comment: thus **conversions described in jls are sorted according the priority** this clause is wrong ?

Comment: no, the second case simply has nothing to do with boxing/unboxing, it is just a reference equality for two objects

Comment: @OlegEstekhin : I never say, it has something with boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose that conversions described in jls are sorted according the priority.

That is incorrect.  The JLS does not talk about "priorities" for conversions.  It is not a recognized concept.

In fact, the conversions that can be applied are documented on a case by case basis for each operator, and so on.  Thus [JLS 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) says that `==` or `!=` for numeric types results in "binary numeric promotion" of both operands.  And [JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) says that binary numeric promotion consists of "unboxing conversion" ([5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) followed by "widening primitive conversion" ([5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) and finally "value set conversion" ([5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

By contrast, [JLS 15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) says that when two references are compared using `==` or `!=`, no promotions or conversions take place.

(In fact, a common Java beginners mistake is to use `==` to compare two `Integer` objects rather than the `equals(Object)` method.  And probably that is what "the question" you are looking at is trying to test your understanding of ...)

Answer (score 0):

`int sn=1000; 
Integer isn1=new Integer(sn);
System.out.println(sn == isn1 );`

will be converted to

`System.out.println(sn == isn1.intValue());`

while comparing primitive with wrapper the wrapper object first will be unboxed and then comparison.
wrapper object intValue() returns int so due to primitive comparison result true.

```
Integer isn1= new Integer(sn);
```

`Integer isn2= new Integer(sn);
System.out.println(isn1 == isn2 );`

// comparing two different object so false.